# Core Data Multiple FetchedResultsController/Views: How do you update all manually?

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have two instances of the same ViewController class accessed in different tab items.  Both use the same entity, but with a different predicate.  One displays all the items, while the other displays a subset based on its predicate.

The problem occurs when I delete an object from the "All" list.  It updates immediately, but when I switch over to the other tab, the object is still there, even after going back and forth in the views.  Only after a period of time, around 5 to 10 seconds, does the deletion get reflected in the other view.

The ViewController class use a FetchedResultsController.

Any ideas what the cause is and how to get the results to immediate appear?

Comment: Another consideration: I'm successful when I use the built-in application master-detail template, but when I try to use a UIManagedDocument, I can't get it to sync right away.  Maybe this is a problem with the ManagedDocument only?

Answer (score 0):

Just put a `reloadData` into `viewWillAppear`. You can also catch this when the tab bar's selected index changes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I've tried that already.  My guess is that it has something to do with the NSManagedObjectContext, because it only happens when I recreate the FetchedResultsController.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there is no solution.  There is no way to update UIManagedDocument manually.

This guy came to the same conclusion:

[Core Data managed object does not see related objects until restart Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437159/core-data-managed-object-does-not-see-related-objects-until-restart-simulator)

So the solution is to use the default master-detail template and to stop using UIManagedDocument.  Wish there was some documentation on this, would have saved me a day of my life.